# Difficulty getting value of textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="message">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="send_message" placeholder="Enter text ...">  </textarea>
    <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">OK</a>
    <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">Cancel</a>
```

when I add:

```
if($(this).is(":contains(Cancel)"))  {

    var text= $("#send_message").val();

    log.console(text)
```

I get the correct value

If I change the line to:

```
    var text= $(this).find("#send_message").val();
```

I get undefined logged to console. Why is this?

Here is the full jQuery function:

```
$(function(){
    $('#message').on("click", "a", function(){

        if( $(this).is(":contains(OK)") ) {

            console.log("im in OK!!");
        }
        else if( $(this).is(":contains(Cancel)") )  {

        //  var text= $("#send_message").val();
            var text= $(this).find("#send_message").val();
            console.log(text);
            console.log("im in cancel!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How is your code being executed? Like what is `this`?

Comment: `find()` looks for elements below the DOM node you're currently in (in this case, `$(this)` refers to your last `a.btn.btn-large.btn-info` link). You want to use `.closest()` instead

Comment: Why would you do that anyway? An id is unique on the page.

Comment: listen to a combination of the two comments above this. You should never have two elements with the same id, so whatever.find('#send_message') should always been the same as $('#sendMessage')

Comment: ^ provided that whatever is a parent of the element whose id is sendMessage. Which it isn't here. So i kinda worded that wrong haha

Comment: full code above. I thought var text= $(this).find("#send_message").val(); would be more efficient and look through less of the DOM

Comment: I think I figured it out: $('#message').on("click", "a", function() sets this to be just 'a' elements. obviously textarea is not included in that - sorry - Bill

Comment: @user61629 I made this [test case](http://jsperf.com/depth-selectors) to demonstrate the difference in your selectors. It's not exactly the same, as it doesn't use `$(this)`, but you should be able to get the idea. [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com) is a great site for setting up test cases to see which selectors are actually more efficient.

Comment: Thanks War10ck, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) *Gets the descendants of each element*

```
Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.
```

That means you are clicking in a `<a>` that is after the `<textarea>` in the DOM, so `.find()` will not look for it backwards.

Anyway to find a element who has ID you need just `$("#send_message")`, and `.val()` to get its value.

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/tYPk3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're closing your div with id message, and also, use `$('#send_message')`. There's absolutely no point in using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with an [`id` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) because as you know ids are intended to be unique (otherwise it's invalid HTML).

Quoting the W3C:

> A unique identifier for the element.
>   There must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value.

Comment: I think I figured it out: $('#message').on("click", "a", function() sets this to be just 'a' elements. obviously textarea is not included in that - sorry  - Bill